# Sequelize & Express. Child elements do not have access to the linked model

Tags: express, sequelize.js, population

Faced a problem. I have two models:

```
//Comment.js

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Comment = sequelize.define('Comment', {
        body: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            notEmpty: true
        },

        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    });

    Comment.associate = (models) => {
        Comment.belongsTo(models.User, {as: 'owner'}),
        Comment.belongsToMany(models.Comment, {as: 'Children', through: 'CommentChildren'}),
        Comment.hasOne(models.Comment, {as: 'Parent', foreignKey: 'ParentId', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    }

    return Comment
}
```

and

```
//User.js

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        login: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            notEmpty: true
        },

        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            notEmpty: true,
            allowNull: false
        },

        status: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM('active', 'inactive'),
            defaultValue: 'active'
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true
    });

    User.associate = (models) => {
        User.hasMany(models.Post)
    }

    return User
}
```

Comments are stored in the Comment model, and the comment can have a parent, and many child comments.

And when I try to execute the query:

```
const comments = await models.Comment.findAll({
                    where: {PostId: post.id},
                    include: [{model: models.User, as: 'owner'}, {model: models.Comment, as: 'Children'}]
                }).catch(console.log)
```

When you try to display this structure in `EJS`, the result set of the first level has access to `{model: models.User, as: 'owner'}` via `comments[0].owner.login`, but the children do not have this property.

```
//Comment.ejs

<% if (items) { %>
  <% if (items.length) { %>
      <ul>
        <% } %>

          <% items.forEach(function(item){ %>
            <li id="<%= item.id %>">
              <div class="head">
                <a href="/users/<%= item.owner.login %>">
                  <%= item.owner.login %>
                </a>
                <spam class="date">
                  <%= moment(item.createdAt).fromNow(); %>
                </spam>
              </div>
              <%= item.body %>
                <span class="link" id="reply">Reply</span>
                <% if (item.Children) {%>
                  <%= include('./comments.ejs', {items: item.Children}) %>
                <% }%>
            </li>
            <% }) %>

              <% if (items.length) { %>
      </ul>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```

If you create elements without children, everything works, but as soon as a child comment is created, an error is thrown that indicates that the deepened element does not have access to `{model: models.User, as: 'owner'}`:

```
    7|             <li id="<%= item.id %>">
    8|               <div class="head">
 >> 9|                 <a href="/users/<%= item.owner.login %>">
    10|                   <%= item.owner.login %>
    11|                 </a>
    12|                 <spam class="date">

Cannot read property 'login' of undefined
```

How do I modify the query to have something like populate in mangoose?